# How to Update UIProgressView to Display NSUrlSession Download Progress After Changing View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a ViewController on which the user can tap a button and start a relatively large download (around 200mb). I have all the correct NSUrlSession delegates in place, and as long the user does not navigate away from the ViewController, a UIProgressView will update perfectly and everything downloads just fine. My problem is that while the file is downloading, I want the user to be able to go to other ViewControllers, but still be able to come back and check the progress of the download.

However, after navigating to a different ViewController and coming back, the delegate methods are not firing for the download task. I can tell with NSLog that the file is still downloading, but the UIProgressView no longer updates because the delegate methods aren't being called. How, when coming back to the page can I grab the currently running download task and fire its delegate methods in order to correctly update the progress view?

When I navigate to the Download File page, I set up the NSUrlSession.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a session with the custom configuration
    self.session = [self backgroundSession];
}

- (NSURLSession *)backgroundSession
{
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken,
              ^{
                  // Session Configuration
                  NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.NSUrlSession.app"];

                  // Initialize Session
                  session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration
                                                          delegate:self
                                                     delegateQueue:nil];
              });

    return session;
}
```

Then I have a button that creates the download task and starts downloading.

```
- (IBAction)downloadMovie:(id)sender
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:LARGE_MOVIE]];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];

    [task resume];
}
```

Here is the delegate method that updates the UIProgressView

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    double progress = (double) (totalBytesWritten/1024) / (double) (totalBytesExpectedToWrite/1024);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       [self.progressView setProgress:progress animated:NO];
                       NSLog(@"%f", progress);
                   });
}
```

Like I said, as long as the user doesn't navigate to a different view controller everything downloads perfectly and the UIProgressView updates correctly. But, if the user leaves and comes back, the the newly instantiated view controller isn't the same as the original one that was assigned as the delegate to the session, so the delegate method isn't firing and its not updating the UIProgressView, even though the file is still downloading in the background as you can tell from the NSLog updates.

Comment: Which delegate functions ? Can you check delegate is still alive ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless In the URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: delegate function, I update the UIProgressview and have an NSLog message displaying the (totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite).

When I go to a different view controller, the NSLog message is still firing displaying the current progress, so I know that the file is still downloading on a background process somewhere.

But, when I go back to the view controller, if I have a breakpoint at that delegate method, the program doesn't stop and the NSLog message still fires.

Comment: @NeverHopeless I'm guessing that if I can grab the active download task and make its delegate the newly instantiated view controller, it will start updating the UIProgressView properly again, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Is it possible for you to print the delegate of NSURLSession in the same NSLog which shows file is still downloading ?

Comment: Also, can you please check if you are not setting delegate = nil somewhere, e.g., `viewDidDisappear` etc.. Can you please show us some code ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless I definitely never set the delegate to nil anywhere.
And I just added an NSLog to print the delegate and this is what it prints.

<SPDownloadViewController: 0x8c24880>

Comment: why do you have TWO `session` variables ? one is static and other one is public property ? Which one do you use to check the delegate is alive ?

Comment: I have an NSLog("%@", session) in the URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite‌​: delegate function that tells me that the delegate is still alive in memory somewhere. 

It displays <SPDownloadViewController: 0x8c24880>.

The static variable is to ensure that there is only one instance of the session between view controllers, so when I navigate back to the page the self.session property will be the same session instance as the one that is still alive in the background.

Comment: I checked to make sure this works and it does. The self.session property has the same memory location as the session instance running in the background, but the delegate of the session is also the view controller running the background.

Comment: user3453929, i facing similar issue. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
- (NSURLSession *)backgroundSession
{
    static NSURLSession *staticSession = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken,
              ^{
                  // Session Configuration
                  NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.NSUrlSession.app"];

                  // Initialize Session
                  staticSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration
                                                          delegate:self
                                                     delegateQueue:nil];
              });

    return staticSession;
}
```

Also, try to `Pause` the download task and `Resume` it again once you are back. See if this helps!

Comment: any solutions to this?

Comment: @LeXeR, asa work around you can detach the download process from view controller and handle it in a separate layer, say in DownloadManager class and once the view controller reappears display the current progress from DownloadManager to ViewController's progress view.

Comment: I had done exactly like that. Still the problem persisted. The problem is, the session downloader gets a new instance when the viewcontroller is presented again. The only solution that worked for me is converting my ViewController into Singleton classes.

Comment: @LeXeR,  yes, singleton is a must. One have to avoid reallocating instance get the recently open session.